# Removing whitespace from the output of a Velocity macro

Tags: replace, velocity, trim, removing-whitespace

I am calling a Velocity macro called #renderwithfallback, to which I don't have access to the source code.  However, the resulting output of this macro call contains leading whitespace, and I'm having trouble removing this.

The call to the macro looks like this (note that this is preceded by a variable called $link.requestBaseURL):

```
$link.requestBaseURL#renderwithfallback({'content': $image, 'params':{'renderMode': 'urlBuilderStandard'}})#end
```

The resulting output looks like this:

http://local.london24.com:8080 /image/policy:1.312:1450097969/Yellow-and-orange-daffodils.jpg?f=default&h=200&w=300&$p$f$h$w=c7ebfa3

As you can see, the URL is broken due to the presence of the whitespace between the 8080 and the forward slash.

I have made many attempts to remove this whitespace, but nothing has worked.  I have tried adding .trim() and .replace(" ","") to the end of the macro call, but this had no effect.  I have also tried assigning the macro call to a Velocity variable like this:

```
#set($imageLocation = "#renderwithfallback({'content': $image, 'params':{'renderMode': 'urlBuilderStandard'}})#end")
```

and then calling the .trim() method on $imageLocation, but that didn't work either.  The #set line printed out the output of the macro straight away, and then when I tried to print out $imageLocation or even $imageLocation.trim() it just came out blank on the webpage.

Does anyone know how I can get rid of the whitespace?

Comment: Sounds really weird. As I see you made sure the whitespace actually origins from that macro (otherwise I'd suggest it must be caused by sth else). I wonder if it is a blank at all. I'm not sure if `.trim()` removes any whitespace character. For sure `replace` just removes the given string. So, try replacing a regex expression like `\s`, `\S` or even other character as in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8255689/velocity-correct-regex-to-remove-control-characters

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I've tried using \s but that had no effect either.  I also tried /n in case the space was actually caused by a line break, but I had no luck with that either.

Comment: Too bad. So, another approach here: First try to replace something you know that is actually there. Just to prevent you from chasing phantoms. Say, `.replace("image", "this_works")`. If working try wild cards in regex. First `.replace("./image", "/image")` then `.replace("^./", "/")`. But careful, the latter just works for the output of that macro, as it looks at the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `$stringUtils.deleteWhitespace(your variable)`